# PHP problema al conectar a BD

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy intentando conectar una app a una BD MySQL pero me da un error que no entiendo.

El código de conexión es:

```
<?php

function conectarDB() {
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'pruebas');

    if($db){
        echo "Se conecto";
    }else{
        echo "No se conecto";
    }
}
```

Y la llamada la hago en

```
<?php
    // Base de datos
    require '../../includes/config/database.php';

    conectarDB();

    require '../../includes/funciones.php';
    incluirTemplate('header'); 
?>

    <main class="contenedor seccion">
        <h1>Crear</h1>
...
```

Este es el error que me da:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in C:\laragon\www\includes\config\database.php:4 Stack trace: #0 C:\laragon\www\admin\propiedades\crear.php(5): conectarDB() #1 {main} thrown in C:\laragon\www\includes\config\database.php on line 4

Comment: Pues tiene pinta de que la extensión para MySQL no está habilitada. En esta pregunta en el sitio original en inglés te indican varias maneras de solucionarlo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25281467/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysqli-connect

Comment: He hecho todo lo que pone pero no consigo que funcione, no sé donde pueda estar el error

Comment: Y si realizas la conexion directamente, igual ocurre el error ??

Comment: Si, la base de datos está funcional ya he comprobado que se conecte desde otros proyectos que no son con php, es problema lo tengo con este conector en específico

Comment: Una cosa que se indica en el enlace pero algo escondida y que no sé si has tenido en cuenta es que si has modificado el fichero php.ini tienes que reiniciar el servidor Apache, no va a coger los cambios en caliente.

Comment: Ejecutar phpinfo te indicará si el módulo está instalado o no https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.phpinfo.php

Comment: Consegui arreglarlo asignando los drivers en php.ini directamente con la ruta en la que están. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Buen día @lRetro, te recomiendo que pongas respondas tu propia pregunta y la marques como solución aceptada, de esa forma otros usuarios también pueden encontrar la solución. Saludos